# PHP page runs Batch file which runs an executable file that should show GUI but it does not

Tags: python, php, batch-file, exec, exe

The title is as specific as it can get. I have a PHP page that executes a batch file via the exec which will execute a python exe that exports data into csv and should prompt the user via a window made with Mbox if the transaction is successful.

**PHP Script**

```
$work = exec("START exec_export.bat",$output);
echo $work;
var_dump($output);
```

**Batch File**

```
cd C:\wamp64\www\path\dist
START transfer_out_exporting.exe
```

**Python Exe**

```
connection.close()
    cursor.close()
    Mbox('Export Succesful! ', 'File Name: '+file_name+".txt", 0)
```

However, it doesn't. Fortunately, it does complete the intended task of the python exe. It exports the data to csv. It just won't display the window. Another problem is once the php file executes the batch file the page will load forever. I have to restart all services from the wamp so that I can use the python exe again. If I manually click the batch file, it will display the prompt window of the python exe.
[Prompt Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/049Wv.png)

I've been searching endlessly for a week already yet none worked for me.  I've wasted time trying to understand some of the solutions since they don't go into the specifics. Yet, still the problem hasn't been solved. Please, can anyone give me a step by step (with full description of each step) on how to fix this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not a solution, but change in your batch file `cd` to `cd /D`…

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this I don't even know where to start.

Comment: @AlexBarker A good explanation would be appreciated. At least, that's what I expected from this site especially from someone with almost 4000 reputation. I believe I'm starting to understand why the PHP page loads forever. It's because the exe process is still running and the windows process by the batch file. I had to end both tasks for the page to stop loading and display the output. I think I need to work around on letting exe and batch script end itself after the exporting is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since there isn't decent answer here yet I will take a stab at it.

Let's start with your python script.  If you are using this script as an automatic process, why does it require human interaction? I am referring to your prompt window on success. This is going to block the python code from returning without hope of ever getting back to PHP execution until someone manually clicks on the dialog.  Additionally, how do you plan on getting the csv file path from that dialog back to PHP or even the csv contents?  This python program is simply not created in a why that can be used by your PHP code or any other automatic process.  Normally, you would use CLI return codes (0 for success and !0 for error) to denote that a program completed successfully.  The CSV output would be better utilized if it were being sent via STDOUT so that it can be read by programs that need to process it. See [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Origin) item #2. "Expect the output of every program to become the input to another, as yet unknown, program. Don't clutter output with extraneous information. Avoid stringently columnar or binary input formats. Don't insist on interactive input."

You probably should use `proc_open` or at least `shell_exec` instead of `exec`.  Using `proc_open` gives you a resource that you can use with `fgetcsv` omitting the need for a file and all of the convolution that goes along with it.

Get rid of that bat script.  It is frivolous, not portable and just adding unnecessary complexity to your solution.

Comment: Finally! Thank you for an actual answer. However, I've deleted the bat file already and used the proc_open yesterdary. I also got rid of the prompt windows since like you said it blocks the python code from returning to PHP. This time I'm using PHP to prompt the user if the exporting is complete. Still, I appreciate the answer. I've read through it and got it all in mind

Answer (score 0):

Probably the process .exe is still running, I think that batch files are not for that proposal. I think too that you can make it differently.

First of all, don't use batch files that way: you need to do an `start /b`, I guess that this will help you to close the .exe without needs to stop everything.

The command `start` just start the program and whatever, you know? `start /b` makes the program start WITH batch, that means: if batch closed, exe closed.

If this don't work too, is simple: first, put the both programs in the PHP code. And, don't use batch, seriously! That is the most out-of-secure thing that you can have in a website or something, if someone changes the batch command, they can do *anything*. And that is not too hard.

**Program1**

```
timeout /t (time in seconds that you think that the process of exportation gets) >nul
taskkill /f /im cmd* >nul
```

**Program 2**

```
cd C:\wamp64\www\path\dist
start /b transfer_out_exporting.exe
```

You can also go into an cmd, navigate to wamp64\www\path\dist and type `transfer_out_exporting -h` or `transfer_out_exporting /h` to see if they have some option to this, I don't use wamp so I can't help you with this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer too! I really thought it would be secure and useful but then again, I'm still a beginner. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Ya, dude, i work in the hacker side too, so if you don't know about what are you making, just a little error can ruin an entire server, is just my recommendation.
to use the batch script even, you can use a py or js script in the middle of the process, one that is not breakable ^^.

Comment: i'm happy to help ^^

Comment: îf you can up vote and accept my answer as the satisfatory, i will be grateful ^^

Comment: I'm trying to upvote yet it doesn't change. I think I need more than 15 reputation